# offset and limit in the /api/views call

Tags: socrata, soda

I am using the the /api/views/.../rows.json call to access the data and the metadata for a dataset, e.g. -
https://data.colorado.gov/api/views/wumm-7awb/rows.json

Problem is I don't want to access all of the data but using limit and offset parameters does not seem to have any effect.

I know about the SODA API endpoint, e.g. https://data.colorado.gov/resource/wumm-7awb.json, that has limit and offset but it doesn't contain the metadata that the /api/views returns

Alternative question - can the /resource API include the metadata?

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `/resource/wumm-yawb.json` endpoint to fetch the data with `$limit` and `$offset` and just use `/api/views/wumm-yawb.json` to fetch the metadata?

What metadata are you looking for? Our team is designing new metadata APIs and it'd be great to know what you're working with.

Comment: I need the columns metadata - in particular the name, data type and description. This info is only in the /views and not in the /resource

Comment: Sorry, I keep hitting return. What I meant to post was that I also get an error calling /resource with a limit - https://data.colorado.gov/resource/wumm-7awb.json&limit=10 gives-

Comment: (Sorry, again - darn stupid post on return functionality).   Anyways, I get the below error when I provide a limit arg - {
  "code" : "not_found",
  "error" : true,
  "message" : "No service found for this URL."
}

Comment: By the way  - here is a first cut at integrating Socrata search into RAMADDA - http://geodesystems.com/repository/search/textform?provider=data.colorado.gov,data.cdc.gov

Comment: You myst prefix `$limit` and `$offset` with dollar signs to designate that you're using a SoQL parameter instead of filtering the dataset: http://dev.socrata.com/docs/paging.html

Comment: The $limit and $offset seem to have no effect on the /views api. I am calling https://data.cdc.gov/api/views/hauf-e9a4/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD Is there any way to not get the data and just get the metadata? If so then I could the call /resource to get the data

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggested earlier with `/api/views/wumm-yawb.json`. That just returns the metadata, without the data.

Comment: Sorry, I was using the /rows.json api  e.g. - https://data.cdc.gov/api/views/w9yp-g533/rows.json I will switch over - thanks!

Comment: all is working now, thanks. Some examples - [federated search](https://geodesystems.com/repository/search/textform?provider=data.colorado.gov,data.cdc.gov),  [Imported content](https://geodesystems.com/repository/search/type/type_socrata_series), series embedded in a [dashboard](https://geodesystems.com/repository/alias/dataintegration)

Comment: Interesting!  For your federated search, are you making use of our new search API? http://labs.socrata.com/docs/search.html

Comment: @JeffMcWhirter if you're using .NET, checkout [SODA.NET](https://github.com/CityofSantaMonica/SODA.NET) - there are methods for obtaining resource metadata (including column info) and a SoQL query builder interface.

Comment: @chrismetcalf - I wasn't using that API. Just added it but have a problem - The columns listed in the metadata json e.g. - [https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/api/views/ecam-8hbr.json] don't match up with the data in the CSV -  https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/ecam-8hbr.csv?$limit=2&$offset=0

Comment: @JeffMcWhirter Yeah, the exact order may differ, but you should be able to match them up on the field names. Let me know if that's not working.